# How can I pass a complex objects as input when using Cadence CLI tool?

Tags: cadence-workflow

Here is a sample workflow and its input struct:

```
func MyWorkflow(ctx cadence.Context, input MyWorkflowParameters) error {
    ...
}

type MyWorkflowParameters struct {
    SomeString: string,
    SomeInteger: int32
}
```

What’s the best way to pass the complex struct above as the `input` parameter to the Cadence CLI tool when starting or signaling a workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` parameter of the Cadence command-line tool accepts values in a few different formats depending on what your workflow expects. Here are examples for three cases:

**1. Single integers or strings:**

```
--input 12345
--input “my-string"
```

**2. Complex objects:**

When the parameter is a struct as in your example, you need to pass a valid JSON encoded object as in the following example:

--input '{"SomeString":"my-string","SomeInteger":12345}'

**3. Multiple parameters:**

If you have a workflow that expects multiple parameters, you need to pass **a single space-delimited string** where each part of the string corresponds to a particular parameter expected by the workflow. The example below shows how you can pass one integer, one string, and one struct parameter, consecutively:

```
--input '12345 "second param" {"SomeString":"my-string","SomeInteger":12345}'
```

**On a related note**, the recommended way to accept input parameters in a workflow is using a single struct parameter. Even though the syntactic sugar in JSON pollutes the CLI command a little bit, especially when all you need to pass is a single parameter, it pays off when you start passing more parameters to the workflow.

Comment: When I pass more than one parameter I get this error. ERROR com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.POJOWorkflowImplementationFactory - Failure deserializing signal input for "ProductOrchestrator::serviceAcquired" at eventID 43. Dropping it.
com.uber.cadence.converter.DataConverterException: when parsing:""456" "true"" into following types: [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]

Answer (score 1):

For multiple params, use array:

```
--input '["a","b",123]'
```